# how to let Ubuntu see that I increased disk size in azure portal

Tags: azure, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu 18 VM on Azure with one 30 GB SSD disk. unfortunately, the disk free space reached zero, and mysql service went down. I stopped the VM and increased the disk space on Azure portal to 60 GB, but when I start the VM again, Ubuntu keeps showing 100% use of 30 GB. it did not notice the new space.. is there any command I have to run on Ubuntu server in order to see the new size?

Comment: https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-expanding-the-virtual-machine-disk/

Answer (score 1):

I just found that `cfdisk` can solve the whole issue. however if you get errors while running the `cfdisk` command, run `parted` and type `print` and you will get an option to Fix or Ignore the disk space. type `Fix` and then run `cfdisk` again and it will work perfectly. using `cfdisk`, you can resize, delete, create partitions as required.

Answer (score 0):

If your disk is 0 bytes free, Azure is unable to load VM agent and the new disk size won't be updated on Linux.

In this case, you must free some space first, and then run `lsblk` to get the main partition id (i.e. /dev/sdb1)

Then run `growpart /dev/sdb 1` (if your partition id is /dev/sbd1)